# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable in JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

Im attempting to load a TensorFlow model into a javascript file and I'm getting an uncaught TypeError from a line but cant understand why I'm getting that error.

this is the block of code from which the error comes

```
const demosSection = document.getElementById('demos');

const MODEL_FILE_URL = 'models/Graph/model.json';

// For Keras use tf.loadLayersModel().
const model = tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_FILE_URL);

// Before we can use COCO-SSD class we must wait for it to finish
// loading. Machine Learning models can be large and take a moment to
// get everything needed to run.
model.then(function(loadedModel) {
    MODEL_FILE_URL = loadedModel;
    // Show demo section now model is ready to use.
    demosSection.classList.remove('invisible');
});
```

and this was the console error message - `letsscan1.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. at letsscan1.js:12`

Comment: Either you need to make `MODEL_FILE_URL` not `const`, or you shouldn't assign `loadedModel` to it. Does `model.then` return a new *URL*? Doesn't really sound like it, but who knows… If it doesn't return a *URL*, you probably shouldn't assign it to a variable called "URL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` type variables are of `final` type. Once this variable is assigned a value, its value cannot be changed.

You are overriding it here.

```
const demosSection = document.getElementById('demos');

let MODEL_FILE_URL = 'models/Graph/model.json'; // <-- this variable gets assigned another value below. Changed it to let

// For Keras use tf.loadLayersModel().
const model = tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_FILE_URL);

// Before we can use COCO-SSD class we must wait for it to finish
// loading. Machine Learning models can be large and take a moment to
// get everything needed to run.
model.then(function(loadedModel) {
    MODEL_FILE_URL = loadedModel; // <-- you were reassigning a value to a const variable here.
    // Show demo section now model is ready to use.
    demosSection.classList.remove('invisible');
});
```